# How do I set a recognized Apache DocumentRoot under Lion?

Tags: apache, macos

I have a fresh Lion install, and to configure Apache, I've edited all of the references to DocumentRoot (and the Directory entry for DocumentRoot) to "/Users/jonathan/mirror" (with or without quotes as the original path was with or without quotes). Pointing my browser to localhost gives a 404:

```
Not Found

The requested URL / was not found on this server.

Apache/2.2.20 (Unix) DAV/2 Server at localhost Port 80
```

How can I up /Users/jonathan/mirror with appropriate permissions?

Comment: Any reason you don't want to use [MAMP](http://mamp.info)? It's free and self contained (you don't have to mess with Apple's files)

Comment: Never mind; I copied the httpd.conf from the old server.

Comment: In the days of yore I was a system administrator and I usually prefer to work with things unbundled as far as Unix goes. I've had a rough experience with XAMPP sometime back.

Comment: Did you enable virtual hosts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things do doublecheck:

**1. File permissions**

The specified path for the new document root should allow at least read access for the Apache user, which is _www by default. You probably want to `chmod 755 /Users/jonathan/mirror` if the file permissions are too restrictive. What are the actual file permissions on the directory and files?

**2. Virtual hosts**

When you enable name based virtual hosts, the document root in the main config is ignored. Instead the root for the matching hostname will be used, and if none match **it will default to the first virtual host**.